# Why is the type of this OCaml code snippet wrong?

Tags: ocaml, memoization

I am learning the concept of "memoized function" in OCaml, and I tried to implement by myself.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
type 'a memo_type = Value of 'a | Exn of exn

let memo_func_hash_exp f =
  let cache = Hashtbl.create 10 in
  fun v ->
    try
      match Hashtbl.find cache v with
      | Value r -> r
      | Exn e -> e
    with
    | Not_found ->
      begin
        try
         let r = f v in
          Hashtbl.replace cache v (Value r);
          r
        with
        | e ->
            Hashtbl.replace cache v (Exn e);
            raise e
       end  ;;
```

However, to my surprise, the interpreter shows me the type of function `memo_func_hash_exp` is like this:

```
val memo_func_hash_exp : ('a -> exn) -> 'a -> exn = <fun>
```

It seems weird and I have no idea which part of the implementation goes wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the type of this expression:

```
  match Hashtbl.find cache v with
  | Value r -> r
  | Exn e -> e
```

In some cases it returns `r` and in other cases it returns `e`. Hence these must be the same type. Since you cache the value of the function as `r` and exceptions as `e` it follows that `r` is an exception.

It's more likely that you want to *raise* the exception if that's what's in your table.

Comment: Aha.. I should write it in `|Exn e -> raise e` !

Comment: If `e` is `Not_found` you have some ambiguity. But it's definitely closer to working (I think).

Comment: If `e` is `Not_found`, `| Exn e -> raise e` will be catched by your handler just below, so that you will recompute `f v` (and re-raise the `Not_found` exception.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeffrey suggests, this runs into trouble when `Exn e` is `Not_found`, because that exception is confused with the one raised by `Hashtbl.find` to indicate absence in the table. You can avoid this by rearranging the code to move `raise e` out of the scope of the problematic `try`:

```
type 'a memo = Value of 'a | Exn of exn

let memo_func f =
  let cache = Hashtbl.create 16 in
  fun x ->
    let result =
      try Hashtbl.find cache x
      with Not_found ->
        let entry =
          try Value (f x)
          with e -> Exn e in
        Hashtbl.add cache x entry;
        entry in
    match result with
     | Value v -> v
     | Exn e -> raise e
```

Answer (score 1):

below is your code:

```
type 'a memo_type = Value of 'a | Exn of exn

let memo_func_hash_exp f =
  let cache = Hashtbl.create 10 in
  fun v ->
    try
      match Hashtbl.find cache v with
      | Value r -> r
      | Exn e -> e
    with
    | Not_found ->
      begin
        try
         let r = f v in
          Hashtbl.replace cache v (Value r);
          r
        with
        | e ->
            Hashtbl.replace cache v (Exn e);
            raise e
       end  ;;
```

let's break your code down.

First import part is

```
try
  match Hashtbl.find cache v with
  | Value r -> r
  | Exn e -> e
with
```

Basically, what you are trying to do is 1). if Hashtbl find the key `v`, then return its value; 2). if not found, then throw an exception and the outer `try with` will catch it.

However, there comes the first error your code has: you should `raise e`, not return e after `| Exn e ->`.

Anyhow, if you use `e` instead of `raise e`, this part of code implies

1. type of `r` = type of `e`
2. type of `r` = whatever will be returned after the `with`

Then let's assume it catches the exception indicating not found:

```
| Not_found ->
      begin
        try
         let r = f v in
          Hashtbl.replace cache v (Value r);
          r
        with
        | e ->
            Hashtbl.replace cache v (Exn e);
            raise e
       end
```

You see, `with | e -> ...` is there, so `e` is `exn`, and recall r's type = e's type, so r's type is `exn`.

So the whole `memo_func_hash_exp` will return type of `exn`, correct?

Since `r = f v` and `r` might also be returned, the 2nd `r` also has type of `exn`.

So overall, `val memo_func_hash_exp : ('a -> exn) -> 'a -> exn = <fun>`

---

The correct version could be:

```
type 'a memo_type = Value of 'a | Exn of exn

let memo_func_hash_exp f =
  let cache = Hashtbl.create 10 in
  fun v ->
    if Hashtbl.mem cache v then
      match Hashtbl.find cache v with
      | Value r -> r
      | Exn e -> raise e
    else
      try let r = f v in Hashtbl.add cache v (Value r); r
      with e -> Hashtbl.add cache v (Exn e); raise e
```

Basically, you use direct `Hashtbl.mem` to check membership first, this will avoid the confusion of exceptions (one exn could be thrown due to not found, the other due to possible exn that f might throw).